# PDO bindParam() fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to learn PDO, now I have written this small piece of code, but it gives me a fatal error:

**Fatal error:** Call to a member function bindparam() on a non-object in...

```
$con =  new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","csvdangercheck");
$query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `testtabel` (`ID`, `var1`, `var2`) VALUES (:ID , :var1, :var2);");
$query->bindParam(':ID', $id);
$query->bindParam(':var1',$val1);
$query->bindParam(':var2',$val2);
$query->execute();
```

I tried using `print_r($con->errorInfo());` but this returned the following:

**Fatal error:** Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo() in...

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: You are mixing mysqli and pdo. Pick one :) I suggest PDO as your choice.

Comment: Ah that explains alot, Thanks I'll look up some more information then! :)

Comment: @Fluffeh I got it working now :D Thanks, another question.. It's now showing the array which it puts in the database, is there any way of hiding that?

Comment: Mysqli won't "show" an array on it's own. I am guessing you have a print_r or var_dump in there somewhere as you were trying to debug the code?

Comment: Oh yeah, its the print_r I was talking about in the question, you are a hero! :)

Comment: I try to help folks if I can. Seems the nice thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like Fluffeh said, you are mixing up PDO and mysqli, try this:

```
$con =  new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=csvdangercheck', 'root', '');
```